# Android Connect to wifi with programmatic WifiConfiguration

Tags: android, configuration, wifi

I have a problem when I want to connect my device to an existing network wifi.

That is the situation:

I am looking to an existing configured network, if there is not the one I am looking for I build it and then I try to connect the phone.

When the wifi configuration is built manually using the phone interface, I can find it and then connect to it. 
But when I tried to build the configuration programmaticly Android cannot connect the phone to the network.

I have got the following message : "Association request to the driver failed".

I am wondering if the association that failed is the association between the scanned network and the configurated network. BUt I don't know why and so I don't know how to manage this problem.

EDIT: And I forget to say, that my WifiConfiguration is exactly the same as the one is created manually because I get the info from the conf with some logs.

EDIT2 : Here is my wificonf (network is protected by a wep key) :

> ```
>   WifiConfiguration wifiConf = new WifiConfiguration();
>     wifiConf.SSID = "\"ssid\"";
>     wifiConf.wepKeys[0] = "\"password\"";
>     wifiConf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
>     wifiConf.hiddenSSID = false;
>     wifiConf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;
>     wifiConf.priority = 40;
>     wifiConf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
>     wifiConf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
>     wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
>     wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
>     wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);//+
>     wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);//+
>     wifiConf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
>     wifiConf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
>     wifiConf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
>     wifiConf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
>     wifiConf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
> ```

EDIT3 : I already add the permission in AndroidManifest :

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
>       uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"
>       uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"

I hope my problem is clear and hope too that someone could help me.

Comment: could you post some code excerpts where you create it and trying to connect to it. thank you.

Comment: [here][1] you will get your answer. It helped me also.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct form of this setting:

`wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";`

Comment: sorry, this answer isn't clear.  can you add some more detail?