# Enumerate wifi connections and connect to the one not protected with pwd

Tags: android, wifi

I need to enumerate all avaliable wifi connections and connect to the one which is not password protected. Any help/link/suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: hope following answer will help you :

[How to connect to a specific wifi network in Android programmatically?]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html). You'll find a way to request for a WiFi scan : startScan(), retrieve the results (using a BroadcastReceiver) : getScanResults() and check within those results which access points provide you password-free association. addNetwork() and enableNetwork() will help you to connect to any of those.