# WiFi Connectivity Android application

Tags: android, wifi

I am an android developer. I am facing a issue working with WiFi configuration. I need to connect to WiFi when someone opens my application. User has to configure WiFi and only after that app continues. I provide the list of nearest networks, and user has to select his known network. User has to enter the password of the selected network. How can i check if the user has entered the valid/correct password to enable WiFi connectivity.

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android generally already manages its own WiFi connectivity, doesn't it? Wouldn't it be better to simply check whether the user is already connected, and if not - give them a message asking them to connect? Otherwise you're re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect to a specific wifi network in Android programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. Just try to connect to defined AP and verify the result:

```
WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
...
   // If password is empty, it should be left untouched
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(pswd)) {
            if (pswd.length() == 64) {
                // Goes unquoted as hex
                wc.preSharedKey = pswd;
            } else {
                // Goes quoted as ASCII
                wc.preSharedKey = TextUtil.convertToQuotedString(pswd);
            }
        }



int res = -1;

res = m_WifiManager.addNetwork(wc);

boolean b = m_WifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);      

        if(b == true){

            fixSupplicant();

            m_WifiManager.saveConfiguration();

            //success
        }
        else{           
            //failed
 ....






 private void fixSupplicant() {
    final SupplicantState state = m_WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSupplicantState();
    boolean isReconnectDone = false;

    if ((state == SupplicantState.SCANNING)
            || (state == SupplicantState.DISCONNECTED) 
            || (state == SupplicantState.DORMANT)) {
        isReconnectDone = m_WifiManager.reconnect();;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Can you please still make the thing easier for me to understand. A working example will be really helpful.

Comment: @user1886887 Do you want example to create WiFi profile with paswd and to connect to?

Comment: yes. Thats wat i am looking for. Once the user choose the a network from the list i display(Nearest wifi connections), I shall display a alertbox asking him to enter password. i need to check if he has given the correct password and then intent to next page. This is what i need friend..

Comment: I get error in this line.    csWifiTempConfig.preSharedKey = TextUtils.convertToQuotedString(strWifiPwd);. I have declared strWifiPwd as String. I get error in "convertToQuotedString"  and error is "The method convertToQuotedString(String) is undefined for the type TextUtils".

Comment: @user1886887 you can write it by yourself, this method just convert string to "string"  (add quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` for the action [WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) of `WifiManager`.
Then your receiver will be called when the Wifi state changed so when the user connect his phone to a wifi network.