# Programmatically connect to specific wifi network in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, wifi

I want to connect a specific wifi network programatically using the ssid name, password and network type. For Android I found a solution: [How do I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290)
But for BlackBerry I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming for BlackBerry OS 5 or above you may be able to use the [HotspotClientRegistry](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/wlan/hotspot/HotspotClientRegistry.html).

Comment: iam new to this bb development.can u tell with any example.i want to connect to wifi network based on ssid name,password and network type.plz help.....

Comment: wasn't this added in [OS 5.0](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/wlan/hotspot/HotspotClientRegistry.html), or was the ability to initiate a connection not added until BB 6?

Comment: Quite right Nate. I must have miss read the since.. in the API docs. Correction made.