# Programmatically connect to an android device in Portable hotspot

Tags: android, wifi

I have succesfully created a portable hotspot programmatically on my device with a specified SSID. Now I want to connect to it from another device! I'm using this code:

```
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"" + "TinyBox" + "\"";
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
        if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + "TinyBox" + "\"")) {
             wifiManager.disconnect();
             wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
             wifiManager.reconnect();               
             break;
        }           
    }
```

But nothing happens. Where is the mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So guys I found the problem! The SSID was wrong because of the quotes "". So if you create an open portable hotspot with the following code (I took it somewhere on the net):

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
    {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);          
    }       
    Method[] wmMethods = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();   //Get all declared methods in WifiManager class     
    boolean methodFound=false;
    for(Method method: wmMethods){
        if(method.getName().equals("setWifiApEnabled")){
            methodFound=true;
            WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
            netConfig.SSID = "\""+"TinyBox"+"\"";
            netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);

            try {
                boolean apstatus=(Boolean) method.invoke(wifiManager, netConfig,true);          
                for (Method isWifiApEnabledmethod: wmMethods)
                {
                    if(isWifiApEnabledmethod.getName().equals("isWifiApEnabled")){
                        while(!(Boolean)isWifiApEnabledmethod.invoke(wifiManager)){
                        };
                        for(Method method1: wmMethods){
                            if(method1.getName().equals("getWifiApState")){
                                int apstate;
                                apstate=(Integer)method1.invoke(wifiManager);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(apstatus)
                {
                    System.out.println("SUCCESSdddd");  

                }else
                {
                    System.out.println("FAILED");   

                }

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }      
    }
```

You need to connect to it using:

```
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"\"" + "TinyBox" + "\"\"";
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
        if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"\"" + "TinyBox" + "\"\"")) {
            try {
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                System.out.print("i.networkId " + i.networkId + "\n");
                wifiManager.reconnect();               
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }           
    }
```

Comment: this will add quotes two times like `""Tinybox""` , is this is the right method

Comment: it always breaks at "for( WifiConfiguration i : list )" .. what might be the problem ? ( a newbe)

Comment: @phcaze is it possible to give Password?

Comment: @Suda.nese you should first enable the wifi like this.
manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (!manager.isWifiEnabled())
        {
            manager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
then it won't break

Comment: @phcaze This is possible into startLocalOnlyHotspot method ?
i have try to change password but unable to do.