# Wifi connection code

Tags: android, xml, wifi

I need a code which can connect my apps and my computer via a router.
I'm quite a newbie so what code should I add into it?
It's function: The data(could be alphabet or number) can be received by my UDP test tool on my computer after I click the toggle button on my apps. 
I'm just have a blur ideal about it such as : if (tgbutton.isChecked()) ????? else ??????

```
package com.example.ledgo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ToggleButton tgbutton;
    private Activity activity;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        activity = this;

        tgbutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        tgbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (tgbutton.isChecked()) {
```

or is this code correct? there are error on "sendData" and "connectSocket"

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  if (tgbutton.isChecked()){
  mBytes[0] = (byte) (127);
  sendData(mBytes[0]);
  connectSocket("192.168.0.100");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225232/programmatically-connect-to-an-android-device-in-portable-hotspot

Comment: er... can't understand