# Connect to WiFi programmatically in Google Android?

Tags: java, android, networking, wifi

I'm attempting to follow a basic Android Wifi tutorial to enable wifi capabilities within my app however anytime I try to execute it - the wifi connection is never established.

I followed the SO tutorial/example exactly, no bugs, or problems in eclipse, I launch the app... then poof: nothing happens.

P.S.

There is some interesting activity in my logcat - I have a feeling it may explain why I cannot connect.

TUTORIAL / EXAMPLE SOURCE:

[How do I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)

SOURCE:

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.content.Context; 

public class Connect extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.connect);
        String networkSSID = "ANDRE-PC_NETWORK";
        String networkPass = "<password-ommited>";
        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";   //ssid must be in quotes
        conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkSSID + "\""; ; 
        conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40); 
        conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE); 
        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
                 wifiManager.disconnect();
                 wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                 wifiManager.reconnect();
                 break;
            }           
         }
    }}
```

If you see anything interesting in my logcat - let me know!

I don't even know where to start...

LOGCAT w key in HEX:

```
04-04 10:47:29.712: W/SignalStrength(675): getCdmaLevel =4
04-04 10:47:29.712: W/SignalStrength(675): getEvdoLevel =4
04-04 10:47:29.712: W/SignalStrength(675): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 99 0 -76 -25 -92 -25 5 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma 0x4401)
04-04 10:47:29.712: W/SignalStrength(852): getCdmaLevel =4
04-04 10:47:29.712: W/SignalStrength(852): getEvdoLevel =4
04-04 10:47:29.712: W/SignalStrength(852): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 99 0 -76 -25 -92 -25 5 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma 0x4401)
04-04 10:47:29.712: W/SignalStrength(852): getCdmaLevel =4
04-04 10:47:29.712: W/SignalStrength(852): getEvdoLevel =4
04-04 10:47:29.712: W/SignalStrength(852): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 99 0 -76 -25 -92 -25 5 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma 0x4401)
04-04 10:47:29.712: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(852): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -76 -25 -92 -25 5 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma 0x4401 level=4
04-04 10:47:29.712: W/AlarmManager(675): FACTORY_ON= 0
04-04 10:47:29.722: W/SignalStrength(675): getDbm=-76
04-04 10:47:29.722: W/SignalStrength(675): getCdmaAsuLevel=8
04-04 10:47:29.722: W/SignalStrength(675): getEvdoAsuLevel=2
04-04 10:47:29.722: W/SignalStrength(675): getAsuLevel=2
04-04 10:47:31.313: W/PowerManagerService(675): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
04-04 10:47:31.313: I/PowerManagerService(675): Ulight 0x7->0x3|0x0
04-04 10:47:31.313: D/LightsService(675): setLightLocked is called
04-04 10:47:31.624: E/SMD(187): DCD ON
04-04 10:47:31.644: D/PowerManagerService(675): lightSensorChangedLocked value=73 immediate=false
04-04 10:47:31.644: D/PowerManagerService(675): getAutoBrightnessValue : in bound ( 45 < 73 <= 1372 )
04-04 10:47:31.644: D/PowerManagerService(675): getAutoBrightnessValue : in bound ( 45 < 73 <= 1372 )
04-04 10:47:31.644: D/PowerManagerService(675): lcdValue 130
04-04 10:47:31.644: D/PowerManagerService(675): buttonValue 130
04-04 10:47:31.644: D/PowerManagerService(675): keyboardValue 0
04-04 10:47:31.644: D/PowerManagerService(675): lightSensorChangedLocked : mKeyboardLight : 0
04-04 10:47:32.254: W/SignalStrength(675): getCdmaLevel =5
04-04 10:47:32.254: W/SignalStrength(675): getEvdoLevel =4
04-04 10:47:32.254: W/SignalStrength(675): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 99 0 -69 -25 -92 -25 5 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma 0x4501)
04-04 10:47:32.254: W/SignalStrength(852): getCdmaLevel =5
04-04 10:47:32.254: W/SignalStrength(852): getEvdoLevel =4
04-04 10:47:32.254: W/SignalStrength(852): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 99 0 -69 -25 -92 -25 5 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma 0x4501)
04-04 10:47:32.254: W/SignalStrength(852): getCdmaLevel =5
04-04 10:47:32.254: W/SignalStrength(852): getEvdoLevel =4
04-04 10:47:32.254: W/SignalStrength(852): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 99 0 -69 -25 -92 -25 5 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma 0x4501)
04-04 10:47:32.254: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(852): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -69 -25 -92 -25 5 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 cdma 0x4501 level=4
04-04 10:47:32.264: W/SignalStrength(675): getDbm=-69
04-04 10:47:32.264: W/SignalStrength(675): getCdmaAsuLevel=16
04-04 10:47:32.264: W/SignalStrength(675): getEvdoAsuLevel=2
04-04 10:47:32.264: W/SignalStrength(675): getAsuLevel=2
04-04 10:47:32.264: W/AlarmManager(675): FACTORY_ON= 0
04-04 10:47:33.055: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
04-04 10:47:34.427: E/MP-Decision(1542): UP Ld:88 Nw:1.990000 Tw:140 rq:1.500000 seq:147.000000
04-04 10:47:34.437: D/dalvikvm(29031): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 87% free 565K/4096K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 4ms
04-04 10:47:34.617: E/SMD(187): DCD ON
04-04 10:47:34.757: E/MP-Decision(1542): DOWN Ld:29 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 rq:1.000000 seq:195.000000
04-04 10:47:35.147: D/PowerManagerService(675): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1026000  uid : 1000  pid : 675  tag : ActivityManager
04-04 10:47:35.147: W/ActivityManager(675): mDVFSLock.acquire()
04-04 10:47:35.167: D/Launcher.HomeFragment(1074): onPause
04-04 10:47:35.167: D/widget(1074): [MSC_HERO_Accu_JB]>>> WC:1232 [0:0]  fireOP
04-04 10:47:35.167: D/Launcher(1074): onPause, Launcher: 1105102976
04-04 10:47:35.167: D/widget(1074): [MSC_HERO_Accu_JB]>>> WC:1037 [0:0]  onPause 
04-04 10:47:35.167: V/WindowManager(675): rotationForOrientationLw(orient=-1, last=0); user=0  mLidState=-1 mDockMode=0 mHdmiPlugged=false mAccelerometerDefault=false sensorRotation=-1
04-04 10:47:35.187: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.197: D/dalvikvm(29049): GC_CONCURRENT freed 104K, 86% free 588K/4096K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 3ms
04-04 10:47:35.197: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.217: D/Launcher(1074): onTrimMemory. Level: 20
04-04 10:47:35.237: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.247: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(192): <CreateImage:897>: Android Image
04-04 10:47:35.247: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(192): <GetImageAttributes:1162>: RGBX_8888
04-04 10:47:35.257: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.257: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.268: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(192): <CreateImage:897>: Android Image
04-04 10:47:35.268: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(192): <GetImageAttributes:1106>: RGBA_8888
04-04 10:47:35.268: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.298: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.358: E/MP-Decision(1542): UP Ld:98 Nw:1.990000 Tw:140 rq:1.500000 seq:188.000000
04-04 10:47:35.358: E/wpa_supplicant(1553): Line 0: Too long WEP key 0 '"73:75:70:65:72:6d:61:6e"'.
04-04 10:47:35.358: E/WifiConfigStore(675): failed to set wep_key0: "73:75:70:65:72:6d:61:6e"
04-04 10:47:35.358: E/WifiConfigStore(675): Failed to set a network variable, removed network: 10
04-04 10:47:35.388: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.388: D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService(675): setSystemUiVisibility(0x0)
04-04 10:47:35.388: D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService(675): manageDisableList what=0x0 pkg=WindowManager.LayoutParams
04-04 10:47:35.408: I/ClipboardServiceEx(675): Send intent for dismiss clipboard dialog inside hideCurrentInputLocked() !
04-04 10:47:35.458: E/Sensors(675): accelHandler 2.301614 0.295785 9.055569
04-04 10:47:35.458: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.458: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(192): <CreateImage:897>: Android Image
04-04 10:47:35.458: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(192): <GetImageAttributes:1162>: RGBX_8888
04-04 10:47:35.468: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.468: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.598: D/PowerManagerService(675): releaseDVFSLockLocked : all DVFS_MIN_LIMIT are released 
04-04 10:47:35.598: D/Launcher.HomeFragment(1074): onStop
04-04 10:47:35.598: D/Launcher(1074): onStop, Launcher: 1105102976
04-04 10:47:35.598: W/ActivityManager(675): mDVFSLock.release()
04-04 10:47:35.608: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.658: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.668: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.668: D/KeyguardViewMediator(675): setHidden false
04-04 10:47:35.928: E/MP-Decision(1542): DOWN Ld:19 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 rq:0.000000 seq:217.000000
04-04 10:47:36.379: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): nl80211: Received scan results (3 BSSes)
04-04 10:47:36.379: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-NO-CONNECTION
04-04 10:47:36.379: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): wpa_supplicant_req_new_scan: wpa_s->global->bStopPeriodicScan : 0, timeout_sec : 8
04-04 10:47:36.379: D/Tethering(675): interfaceLinkStateChanged wlan0, true
04-04 10:47:36.379: D/Tethering(675): interfaceStatusChanged wlan0, true
04-04 10:47:36.389: W/AlarmManager(675): FACTORY_ON= 0
04-04 10:47:36.399: W/AlarmManager(675): FACTORY_ON= 0
04-04 10:47:37.620: E/SMD(187): DCD ON
04-04 10:47:39.122: I/rmt_storage(128): rmt_storage_rw_iovec_cb: /boot/modem_fs2: clnt_h=0x2: req_h=0x6ae msg_id=3: R/W request received
04-04 10:47:39.122: I/rmt_storage(128): wakelock acquired: 1, error no: 110
04-04 10:47:39.122: I/rmt_storage(128): rmt_storage_client_thread: /boot/modem_fs2: clnt_h=0x2 Unblock worker thread (th_id: 1103109840)
04-04 10:47:39.122: D/QMI_FW(128): QCSI: QMI_CSI_RX: cntl_flag - 00, txn_id - 0356, msg_id - 0003, msg_len - 002b
04-04 10:47:39.222: D/QMI_FW(128): QCSI: xport_handle_event[16]
04-04 10:47:39.302: I/rmt_storage(128): rmt_storage_client_thread: /boot/modem_fs2: clnt_h=0x2: req_h=0x6ae msg_id=3: Bytes written = 3145216
04-04 10:47:39.302: I/rmt_storage(128): rmt_storage_client_thread: /boot/modem_fs2: clnt_h=0x2: req_h=0x6ae msg_id=3: Bytes written = 512
04-04 10:47:39.302: I/rmt_storage(128): rmt_storage_client_thread: /boot/modem_fs2: clnt_h=0x2: req_h=0x6ae msg_id=3: Send response: res=0 err=0
04-04 10:47:39.302: I/rmt_storage(128): rmt_storage_client_thread: /boot/modem_fs2: clnt_h=0x2 About to block rmt_storage client thread (th_id: 1103109840) wakelock released: 1, error no: 0
04-04 10:47:39.302: D/QMI_FW(128): QCSI: QMI_CSI_TX: cntl_flag - 02, txn_id - 0356, msg_id - 0003, msg_len - 0007
04-04 10:47:39.302: D/QMI_FW(128): QCSI: Sent[16]: 14 bytes to port 1280
04-04 10:47:39.452: D/PowerManagerService(675): lightSensorChangedLocked value=69 immediate=false
04-04 10:47:39.452: D/PowerManagerService(675): getAutoBrightnessValue : in bound ( 45 < 69 <= 1372 )
04-04 10:47:39.452: D/PowerManagerService(675): getAutoBrightnessValue : in bound ( 45 < 69 <= 1372 )
04-04 10:47:39.452: D/PowerManagerService(675): lcdValue 130
04-04 10:47:39.452: D/PowerManagerService(675): buttonValue 130
04-04 10:47:39.452: D/PowerManagerService(675): keyboardValue 0
04-04 10:47:39.452: D/PowerManagerService(675): lightSensorChangedLocked : mKeyboardLight : 0
04-04 10:47:39.762: V/AT_Distributor(200): received[idx : 0, fd : 11] : UART, 1
04-04 10:47:40.623: E/SMD(187): DCD ON
```

LOGCAT: without key in HEX

```
04-04 11:27:25.210: V/AT_Distributor(200): received[idx : 0, fd : 11] : UART, 1
04-04 11:27:25.240: E/SMD(187): DCD ON
04-04 11:27:26.741: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): State: DISCONNECTED -> SCANNING
04-04 11:27:26.741: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=10 state=3 BSSID=00.00.00
04-04 11:27:26.741: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): 414E4452452D50435F4E4554574F524B
04-04 11:27:26.781: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
04-04 11:27:27.182: D/ActivityThread(31678): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
04-04 11:27:27.182: D/ActivityThread(31678): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
04-04 11:27:27.182: D/ActivityThread(31678): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
04-04 11:27:27.202: I/ActivityThread(31678): Pub com.wssyncmldm.ContentProvider: com.wssyncmldm.db.sql.XDMDbContentProvider
04-04 11:27:27.212: I/DBG_DM(31678): [][Line:67][onCreate] 
04-04 11:27:27.232: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:686][xdmGetCheckWifiOnlyModel] isWifiOnly : false
04-04 11:27:27.232: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:701][xdmGetCheckDataOnly] Voice : true
04-04 11:27:27.242: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:702][xdmGetCheckDataOnly] SMS : true
04-04 11:27:27.242: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:709][xdmGetCheckDataOnly] isDataOnly : false
04-04 11:27:27.242: D/dalvikvm(675): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
04-04 11:27:27.422: D/dalvikvm(675): GC_EXPLICIT freed 58K, 28% free 38507K/53191K, paused 7ms+16ms, total 179ms
04-04 11:27:27.422: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:52][onCreate] DMApplication Start !
04-04 11:27:27.432: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:1779][xdmGetRootingPrefValue] 0
04-04 11:27:27.432: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:86][xdmGetRootingFeature] Default : false
04-04 11:27:27.432: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:172][xdmAgentTaskHandler] XEVENT_OS_INITIALIZED
04-04 11:27:27.442: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:148][xdmAgentSetSyncMode] nSync = 0
04-04 11:27:27.452: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:546][xdmGetEnableLiveDemoFromCSCFeature] enable LiveDemo : false
04-04 11:27:27.462: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:1860][xdbDMffs_Init] xdbDMffs_Init
04-04 11:27:27.472: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:372][xdmInitExternalStorageState] 
04-04 11:27:27.482: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:427][xdmInitExternalStorageState] bExternalStorageAvailable [true]
04-04 11:27:27.482: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:428][xdmInitExternalStorageState] bExternalSDStorageAvailable [false]
04-04 11:27:27.502: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:182][xdmAgentTaskHandler] XEVENT_PHONEBOOK_INITIALIZED
04-04 11:27:27.522: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:1084][onCallStateChanged] >>>>>>>>>>> onCallStateChanged
04-04 11:27:27.522: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:1104][onCallStateChanged] >>>>>>>>>>> CALL_STATE_IDLE
04-04 11:27:27.532: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:1591][xdmProtoIsWIFIConnected] WiFi DisConnected
04-04 11:27:27.532: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:1591][xdmProtoIsWIFIConnected] WiFi DisConnected
04-04 11:27:28.023: E/Watchdog(675): !@Sync 1425
04-04 11:27:28.243: E/SMD(187): DCD ON
04-04 11:27:28.403: D/dalvikvm(31695): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 87% free 565K/4096K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 5ms
04-04 11:27:29.264: D/PowerManagerService(675): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1026000  uid : 1000  pid : 675  tag : ActivityManager
04-04 11:27:29.264: W/ActivityManager(675): mDVFSLock.acquire()
04-04 11:27:29.274: D/dalvikvm(31708): GC_CONCURRENT freed 104K, 86% free 589K/4096K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 4ms
04-04 11:27:29.745: V/AT_Distributor(200): received[idx : 0, fd : 11] : UART, 1
04-04 11:27:30.105: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): nl80211: Received scan results (4 BSSes)
04-04 11:27:30.105: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-NO-CONNECTION
04-04 11:27:30.105: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): wpa_supplicant_req_new_scan: wpa_s->global->bStopPeriodicScan : 0, timeout_sec : 8
04-04 11:27:30.105: W/AlarmManager(675): FACTORY_ON= 0
04-04 11:27:30.115: D/Tethering(675): interfaceLinkStateChanged wlan0, true
04-04 11:27:30.115: D/Tethering(675): interfaceStatusChanged wlan0, true
04-04 11:27:30.115: W/AlarmManager(675): FACTORY_ON= 0
04-04 11:27:30.265: D/PowerManagerService(675): releaseDVFSLockLocked : all DVFS_MIN_LIMIT are released 
04-04 11:27:30.265: W/ActivityManager(675): mDVFSLock.release()
04-04 11:27:30.856: V/AT_Distributor(200): received[idx : 0, fd : 11] : UART, 1
04-04 11:27:31.246: E/SMD(187): DCD ON
04-04 11:27:34.249: E/SMD(187): DCD ON
04-04 11:27:34.530: V/AT_Distributor(200): received[idx : 0, fd : 11] : UART, 1
04-04 11:27:35.651: V/AT_Distributor(200): received[idx : 0, fd : 11] : UART, 1
04-04 11:27:37.153: D/dalvikvm(193): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
04-04 11:27:37.223: D/ActivityThread(31724): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
04-04 11:27:37.223: D/ActivityThread(31724): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
04-04 11:27:37.223: D/ActivityThread(31724): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
04-04 11:27:37.233: D/dalvikvm(193): GC_EXPLICIT freed 38K, 43% free 12111K/20995K, paused 4ms+43ms, total 74ms
04-04 11:27:37.233: D/dalvikvm(193): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
04-04 11:27:37.243: E/SMD(187): DCD ON
04-04 11:27:37.293: D/dalvikvm(193): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 43% free 12111K/20995K, paused 5ms+3ms, total 59ms
04-04 11:27:37.293: I/nmc-java(31724): loadLibrary >>> java.library.path=/vendor/lib:/system/lib
04-04 11:27:37.293: I/nmc-java(31724): loadLibrary >>> data directory=/data
04-04 11:27:37.293: I/nmc-java(31724): loadLibrary >>> packageName=com.nuance.nmc.sihome.metropcs
04-04 11:27:37.293: I/nmc-java(31724): loadLibrary >>> Loading '/data/data/com.nuance.nmc.sihome.metropcs/lib/libnmc.so' ...
04-04 11:27:37.293: E/nmc-java(31724): loadLibrary >>> Unsatisfied link error: Cannot load library: load_library[1093]: Library '/data/data/com.nuance.nmc.sihome.metropcs/lib/libnmc.so' not found
04-04 11:27:37.293: I/nmc-java(31724): loadLibrary >>> Loading '/system/lib/libnmc.so' ...
04-04 11:27:37.303: D/dalvikvm(193): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
04-04 11:27:37.333: D/dalvikvm(193): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 43% free 12111K/20995K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 32ms
04-04 11:27:38.154: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
04-04 11:27:39.455: V/AlarmManager(675): waitForAlarm result :4
04-04 11:27:39.455: V/AlarmManager(675): trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP
04-04 11:27:40.016: V/AT_Distributor(200): received[idx : 0, fd : 11] : UART, 1
04-04 11:27:40.246: E/SMD(187): DCD ON
04-04 11:27:40.536: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:434][xdmInitAdpWaitBearerSetting] waits 13 sec
04-04 11:27:40.536: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:3343][xdbGetFUMOStatus] xdbGetFUMOStatus : 0
04-04 11:27:40.546: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:1759][xdmGetUpdateReport] wssGetUpdateReport : 0
04-04 11:27:40.546: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:207][xdmAgentTaskHandler] XEVENT_DM_INIT
04-04 11:27:40.566: I/SysScopeVerifier(31678): SHA1-Digest :hI/erQ2i2NX0ldg3pB2Zct4P4i8=
04-04 11:27:40.566: I/SysScopeVerifier(31678): SHA1-Digest :MqtHJr/par3LL1huEuNvd7lYic0=
04-04 11:27:40.606: I/SysScopeVerifier(31678): classes.dexMqtHJr/par3LL1huEuNvd7lYic0=
04-04 11:27:40.616: I/SysScopeVerifier(31678): lib/armeabi/libcordon.sohI/erQ2i2NX0ldg3pB2Zct4P4i8=
04-04 11:27:40.626: E/DBG_DM(31678): Warning!!! [v5_1209_3_1][Line:1818][xdmCheckSystemRooting] Device is ok
04-04 11:27:40.626: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:442][xdmInitAdpWaitSystemRootingCheck] Check completed.
04-04 11:27:40.626: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:1591][xdmProtoIsWIFIConnected] WiFi DisConnected
04-04 11:27:40.626: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:54][xdmInitAdpGetNetStatus] SIM : Network unknown
04-04 11:27:40.626: E/DBG_DM(31678): Warning!!! [v5_1209_3_1][Line:214][xdmAgentTaskHandler] Network Status is not ready. DM Not Initialized
04-04 11:27:40.636: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:983][xdmGetTopActivityName] TopActivity : com.nfc.linked.Connect
04-04 11:27:40.636: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:207][xdmAgentTaskHandler] XEVENT_DM_INIT
04-04 11:27:40.646: I/SysScopeVerifier(31678): SHA1-Digest :hI/erQ2i2NX0ldg3pB2Zct4P4i8=
04-04 11:27:40.646: I/SysScopeVerifier(31678): SHA1-Digest :MqtHJr/par3LL1huEuNvd7lYic0=
04-04 11:27:40.666: I/SysScopeVerifier(31678): classes.dexMqtHJr/par3LL1huEuNvd7lYic0=
04-04 11:27:40.676: I/SysScopeVerifier(31678): lib/armeabi/libcordon.sohI/erQ2i2NX0ldg3pB2Zct4P4i8=
04-04 11:27:40.676: E/DBG_DM(31678): Warning!!! [v5_1209_3_1][Line:1818][xdmCheckSystemRooting] Device is ok
04-04 11:27:40.676: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:442][xdmInitAdpWaitSystemRootingCheck] Check completed.
04-04 11:27:40.686: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:1591][xdmProtoIsWIFIConnected] WiFi DisConnected
04-04 11:27:40.686: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:54][xdmInitAdpGetNetStatus] SIM : Network unknown
04-04 11:27:40.686: E/DBG_DM(31678): Warning!!! [v5_1209_3_1][Line:214][xdmAgentTaskHandler] Network Status is not ready. DM Not Initialized
04-04 11:27:40.686: I/DBG_DM(31678): [v5_1209_3_1][Line:983][xdmGetTopActivityName] TopActivity : com.nfc.linked.Connect
04-04 11:27:40.856: V/AT_Distributor(200): received[idx : 0, fd : 11] : UART, 1
04-04 11:27:41.477: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): nl80211: Received scan results (3 BSSes)
04-04 11:27:41.477: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-NO-CONNECTION
04-04 11:27:41.477: I/wpa_supplicant(1553): wpa_supplicant_req_new_scan: wpa_s->global->bStopPeriodicScan : 0, timeout_sec : 8
04-04 11:27:41.477: D/Tethering(675): interfaceLinkStateChanged wlan0, true
04-04 11:27:41.477: D/Tethering(675): interfaceStatusChanged wlan0, true
04-04 11:27:41.497: W/AlarmManager(675): FACTORY_ON= 0
04-04 11:27:41.497: W/AlarmManager(675): FACTORY_ON= 0
04-04 11:27:43.249: E/SMD(187): DCD ON
```

PERMISSIONS:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Comment: Did you had a look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically
Maybe that is helpful

Comment: That is the link I posted in my question - I've used it to get where I am now but it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried disabling security and then connecting ? See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18813643/281545

Comment: Is the device you're testing on running KitKat? Google introduced more aggressive deep sleep behavior in KK; WiFi will not successfully connect after the screen turns off and the device enters deep sleep. You may need a wakelock. Some other pre-KK phones have similar behavior (e.g. Xperia's "Stamina" mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you setup your Wi-Fi connection like this and the logcat shows no errors, debug information or anything of the sort, it usually means your entered preshared key doesn't match the key of the network.
And I think that's because of this line:

```
conf.preSharedKey = "\"+ networkPass +\"";
```

It should be:

```
conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
```

Comment: Ok - I updated the line above and now my logcat looks VERY different - but still no connection to the wifi network. (I've noticed the tutorial would like to view a list of networks and connect to one of them - yet I would like to connect to one network and one network only [Andre-PC_Network] - I'm not sure if that has anything to do with why I can't connect - perhaps because I'm never selecting one?)

Comment: Also - does anyone see anything in my updated logcat (above) that might explain why the app still does not connect me to the wifi network I specified?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
```

to

```
conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code when answering. Thanks!