# How to connect to a saved wifi in android?

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

I know there are methods to add and connect to a wifi network

> [How do I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)

But what I need is to connect to a network that is already been saved by the user in the device,
Basically I want to connect to the best available network (which user has been connected to earlier) around. I can manage to find the nearby wifi signals and get their strength then I want to connect to the best one.

Also there are couple of inactive threads in SO asking the same question, unfortunately none of them has any answers:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257680/connect-to-a-configured-wifi-network
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476702/android-how-do-you-choose-which-previously-saved-wifi-to-connect-to-and-do-it
>   [How to connect to pre-configured Wifi in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474861/how-to-connect-to-pre-configured-wifi-in-android)

Comment: Consider revising your question and heading. Whenever you switch wifi using wifimanager it automatically connects to the network which you have previously connected i.e the one which is saved by the user. I think your question is to connect to network based on signal strenght.

Comment: Not exactly based on the strength, I just want to connect to one of the saved wifi networks, say we have 3 different ,previously saved, available wifi and I want to connect to one of them, but not using the methods to add a network with ssid and password etc ...