# Programmatically get connected Wifi password?

Tags: android, android-wifi

My app needs to communicate with a Sony Wifi camera. The user specifies the camera Wifi SSID and password, the app connects, takes a picture and retrieves it to the android device. When the app is done taking pictures, I want it to restore the Wifi connection (if any) that existed before the app was started. E.g. the user may have been connected to to a coffee shop hotspot when she starts the wifi camera app, and so the the app should automatically reconnect to the hotspot when it's done.

To restore the pre-existing connection, the app needs to know the SSID - and also the password, I think.  It's easy for the app to determine the pre-existing SSID - just call WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID() before switching to the camera Wifi SSID. But how to get the pre-existing password? I don't want to require the user to re-enter that password. Is this functionality possible?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: You can't get the password - that would be a security hole.

Comment: Thanks Mike W. Is there an alternative approach that restores the original Wifi connection without the user needing to re-enter the password?

Comment: Let the user enter the password once (in the beginning): [How to connect to a specific Wifi network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: Anyone know of a way to "cache" the current connection and restore it later? In principle I could see how this *might* be done without revealing the password to the app level, since the Android system "remembers" Wifi passwords - but I just don't know of any provided APIs to to do it.

Comment: I want same kind of app can you provide me some useful links so that I can get started

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`WifiInfo.getNetworkId`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getNetworkId()) API to get current network id and save it for future use.
When you want to connect back to original network use [`WifiManager.enableNetwork`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#enableNetwork(int,%20boolean)) API and pass the network ID you cached before.

Comment: it's possible to fetch wifi password ?