# Free wifi only if my app is installed

Tags: android, networking

I would like to simulate the scenario like it is available in some hotels. Basically, if the user connects to free wifi in a hotel he/she needs to either enter a code, or visit to predefined site to accept terms and conditions.

I would like to replicate the same on android phone, user could only connect to free wifi if my custom application is installed else not.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only possibility if you really want to develop this as an app would be to programmatically connect to the Wifi network. This way, the user would never see the password of the hotspot (As long as the device is not rooted).
However, the user had to start the app in order to get connected to the wifi, and he could uninstall the app and still connect to the Wifi, as the system saves the wifi configuration.

If you want to go this way, you'll have to deal with the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) APIs.

You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8818490/1691231) to a similar question helpful.

Comment: But how does it work in a hotel? For e.g. in a hotel,  I need to enter a new code everyday to connect to same wifi. thanks for the reply, will evaluate.