# How to wait for WifiManager connect, and determine if OK/failed?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am building an app that can use WifiManager to automagically add/connect our WiFi hosting hardware, so that the user can easily get to its webinterface.

The `wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);` part works. It returns immediately and in a few seconds wifi connects. But the webinterface activity is started right away and the WebView quickly timeouts: page could not be loaded.

This is because the WiFi connection takes a few seconds. I am also unable to inform the user about failed connection attempts.

I read up on this and it seems to me that a `BroadcastReceiver` could "poke" my wifi-connect activity into starting the webinterface activity. A bonus would be to also visualize a failed connect.

So, my questions:

- I recon i need a `BroadcastReceiver` for `WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` or `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` ?
- When to register and unregister it?
- Can/may i just put a loop to check a statemachine (and timeout) in between, or would that be bad design and why?

I hope this can be done while staying inside my app instance .. or would that inherently result in bugs when exiting the app while wifi is trying to connect?

**edit:**

As for code; i use WifiManager exactly like so: [How do I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)

Targeting Android 4.1.2, and am using fragments in activities to recycle view/state instances.

Comment: The connection part - some fresh answers might appear [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39101640/1034042) - if not, follow links in question. Determining failure? No idea, timeout maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` and check on the `NetworkInfo` object contained in the Intent that your are connected.

When to register : it's difficult to say without seing your code, but you could probably register just before calling `wifiManager.enableNetwork`