# How to connect to an available WIFI network through our application in android?

Tags: android, wifi, connectivity

I scan for all the WIFI networks and then display them in a `ListView`. Now I want a click on one of the list items to open a `dialog box` asking for confirmation and the password of that access point to be given by the user. (same as the native wifi application do in android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this link [How do I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically) and also add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: i want my app behave same as native wifi app does...that is it opens a dialog box asking for password then make connection...

Answer (score 1):

Use `wifiReciever.wifiScanList.get(pos).SSID` to get the `SSID` and then use `WiFiConfiguration` class to connect...