# Which mobile OS will allow control Wi-Fi connection from code?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, wifi

I need three things (ideal)

1. Connect to special Wi-Fi net by SSID.
2. Opportunity to disable connection to Wi-Fi net.
3. Use 3G from cellurar operator, when Wi-Fi is on. (ideal)

On WP 8.1 I can only ask user to do 1,2 actions. 
I can not even switch off Wi-Fi connection from code!!!!

Will Android allow me to rule Wi-Fi connection from code?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically

Comment: Well... I see - Android can do that. It seems to me - MS does everything to let WP OS die.