# How to Change the Mobile Network Type using android code?

Tags: android

I want to change the network type in android mobile phone. Is there any function for this purpose in java?

Comment: could you please provide some more details on what you need exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to switch to different network operators - The answer is No, you are not able to do that programmatically. There is no API that supports that.

If you want to switch to different wireless networks the answer is Yes, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically) post.

If you would like to check for different kinds of connectivity states - Look [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/).

Good luck, hope this helped!