# Which one is the best practice to connect Wifi under Android?

Tags: java, android, networking, wifi, connectivity

This is about network Wifi how to connect it under android.
But the question is which one is the best practice between [the Code shown at here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically?answertab=active#tab-top)

And... this below? 
Because two of the source code given have a similarity but they're different in configuring the content. Please give a comment / clear answer.

Thanks

```
private void getConnected(){

        // for Wifi Connectivity
        obWifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
        config.SSID = "\""+objOpp.getName()+"\"";
        config.BSSID = objOpp.getID();
        config.priority = 1;
        config.preSharedKey = "\""+ "PASSWORD"+"\"";
        config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;
        config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.CURRENT; config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X); config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
        config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.NONE);
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.LEAP);
        config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);

        obWifiManager.addNetwork(config);

        // start connection 
        obWifiManager.enableNetwork(config.networkId, true);
        obWifiManager.saveConfiguration();

    }
```