# What's the difference between addNetwork()/enableNetwork() and setWifiApConfiguration()?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have seen this hidden API used in android source called `setWifiApConfiguration()` to set up a AP. I have see couple of answers on SO using `addNetwork()` and then `enableNetwork()` (For ex: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)). So what's the difference between the two methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setWifiApConfiguration()` is a HotSpot or Wi-Fi tethering API, where as `addNetwork()` and `enableNetwork()` are regular Wi-Fi operation APIs