# How do i authenticate wi fi password on android entered by the user?

Tags: android

i am building a sample app that displays available networks and then prompts users to select the  network and asks for the wifi password before connecting and sends that password for wi-fi authentication.My question is how do i send that password for wi-fi authentication.
Thanks

Comment: clear answer to your question is there :

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clear answer to your question is there :

[How do I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)

But, this will be suitable for you..bcz u know the SSID 
solution would look something like this:

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", key);

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager).getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
//remember id
int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```