# How to connect to WiFi spot via Android pragmatically?

Tags: java, android, wifi

I have following code, which has to connect to certain WiFi spot with WPA type:

```
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();

conf.SSID = "\"" + sSSID + "\"";

if (wType == WifiType.WPA)
{
    conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ sPass +"\"";
}
else if (wType == WifiType.WEP)
{
    conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + sPass + "\""; 
    conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40); 
}


WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
//
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(conf.networkId, true);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
if (wifiManager.reconnect())
{
     Log.i(TAG, "successfully connected");
}
```

Things is I get in the log message, claiming that `successfully connected` but nothing happens and connection is not obtained. I thought maybe this is just because it takes some time to obtain it and procedure finishes async, but even after waiting a while connection has not be obtained.

Would you tell me what am I doing wrong here? The Android documentation does not give a lot of details regarding WifiManager class.

Comment: have a look here please:-

[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically

Comment: Yes, I've looked and it almost identical example, disconnect is done in order something is already been connected.