# How to connect to the specific device from list of devices using wifi-direct api?

Tags: android

how to connect to the specific device from list of devices after getting peerslist using  wifi P2p API, i'm new to android world please help on this issue

Comment: Hope this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically

Comment: Thanks for ur reply... but i need to do it for wifi-direct api