# Adding wifi networks to Android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to connect to a wifi network so I try this:

```
WifiConfiguration wfc = new WifiConfiguration();

wfc.SSID = "\"".concat( sid ).concat("\"");
wfc.preSharedKey = "\"".concat( pwd ).concat("\"");

WifiManager wfMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int networkId = wfMgr.addNetwork(wfc);
if (networkId != -1) {
    // success, can call wfMgr.enableNetwork(networkId, true) to connect
} else {
    // fails
}
```

but networkId is always -1
where is the error?

The necessary permissions are also added in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574730/unable-to-connect-to-new-wifi-network

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

> Add a new network description to the set of configured networks. The networkId field of the supplied configuration object is ignored.
>
> The new network will be marked DISABLED by default. To enable it,
> called enableNetwork(int, boolean). Parameters config the set of variables that describe the configuration, contained in a WifiConfiguration object.
>
> Returns the ID of the newly created network description. This is used in other operations to specified the network to be acted upon. Returns -1 on failure.

So, my guess is that you need to do this:

```
wfMgr.enableNetwork(netId,true);
```

netId:  the ID of the network in the list of configured networks.

Comment: wfMgr is a WifiManager so the method is public int addNetwork (WifiConfiguration config). There isn't int addNetwork( WifiConfiguration config, boolean xxx )

Comment: If I have netId = -1 I can't use wfMgr.enableNetwork(netId,true);

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
public static void addNewConnection(final String networkSSID, String networkPassword, String securityType, Context context)
    {
        // Default settings for all networks
        wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfig.SSID = "\"".concat(networkSSID).concat("\"");
        wifiConfig.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        wifiConfig.hiddenSSID = true;
        wifiConfig.priority = 40;


        connectToNewWifiConfig(wifiConfig, context);
    }

    private static boolean connectToNewWifiConfig(final WifiConfiguration wc, Context context)
    {
        wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        boolean success = false;
        final int actNetId = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        String prevNetworkSSID = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        int netId = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
        if (netId != ApplicationConstants.INVALID_NETWORK_ID)
        {
            success = wifi.saveConfiguration();
        }
        return success;
    }
```