# Android connect to Open WiFi programmatically by name - which is Best solution?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-service, wifi

I been trying to use two methods to programmatically connect to a open wifi (connective portal) by name.

I used op1, but it only works about 80% of times.

### _____________________________________________________

op1 :

```
public static void connectToWifi(Context context, String networkSSID) {

    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);


    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
        Log.d(TAG + " |connectToWifi()", "i.SSID=> " + i.SSID);

        if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            wifiManager.reconnect();

            Log.d(TAG + " |connectToWifi()", "IF > i.SSID=> " + i.SSID);

            break;
        }else {Log.e(TAG + " |connectToWifi()", "ELSE - FAILED TO CONNECT > i.SSID=> " + i.SSID);}
    }
}//end connectToWifi
```

op2: from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8818490/3792198

```
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
    if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
         wifiManager.disconnect();
         wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
         wifiManager.reconnect();               

         break;
    }           
 }
```

op3:

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", key);

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
//remember id
int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

Or, do you have any suggestions ?
thank you

Comment: op1 worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * ConnectionManager
 */
public class ConnectionManager {
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private static final String WPA = "WPA";
    private static final String WEP = "WEP";
    private static final String OPEN = "Open";
    private final static String TAG = "WiFiConnector";


    public ConnectionManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    public void enableWifi() {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            new ShowToast(context, "Wifi Turned On");
        }
    }

    public int requestWIFIConnection(String networkSSID, String networkPass) {
        try {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            //Check ssid exists
            if (scanWifi(wifiManager, networkSSID)) {
                if (getCurrentSSID(wifiManager) != null && getCurrentSSID(wifiManager).equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
                    new ShowToast(context, "Already Connected With " + networkSSID);
                    return Constants.ALREADY_CONNECTED;
                }
                //Security type detection
                String SECURE_TYPE = checkSecurity(wifiManager, networkSSID);
                if (SECURE_TYPE == null) {
                    new ShowToast(context, "Unable to find Security type for " + networkSSID);
                    return Constants.UNABLE_TO_FIND_SECURITY_TYPE;
                }
                if (SECURE_TYPE.equals(WPA)) {
                    WPA(networkSSID, networkPass, wifiManager);
                } else if (SECURE_TYPE.equals(WEP)) {
                    WEP(networkSSID, networkPass);
                } else {
                    OPEN(wifiManager, networkSSID);
                }
                return Constants.CONNECTION_REQUESTED;

            }
            /*connectME();*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
            new ShowToast(context, "Error Connecting WIFI " + e);
        }
        return Constants.SSID_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    private void WPA(String networkSSID, String networkPass, WifiManager wifiManager) {
        WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
        wc.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
        wc.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
        wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        int id = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(id, true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
    }

    private void WEP(String networkSSID, String networkPass) {
    }

    private void OPEN(WifiManager wifiManager, String networkSSID) {
        WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
        wc.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
        wc.hiddenSSID = true;
        wc.priority = 0xBADBAD;
        wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        int id = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(id, true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
    }

    boolean scanWifi(WifiManager wifiManager, String networkSSID) {
        Log.e(TAG, "scanWifi starts");
        List<ScanResult> scanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        for (ScanResult i : scanList) {
            if (i.SSID != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "SSID: " + i.SSID);
            }

            if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals(networkSSID)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Found SSID: " + i.SSID);
                return true;
            }
        }
        new ShowToast(context, "SSID " + networkSSID + " Not Found");
        return false;
    }

    public String getCurrentSSID(WifiManager wifiManager) {
        String ssid = null;
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            if (connectionInfo != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(connectionInfo.getSSID())) {
                ssid = connectionInfo.getSSID();
            }
        }
        return ssid;
    }

    private String checkSecurity(WifiManager wifiManager, String ssid) {
        List<ScanResult> networkList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        for (ScanResult network : networkList) {
            if (network.SSID.equals(ssid)) {
                String Capabilities = network.capabilities;
                if (Capabilities.contains("WPA")) {
                    return WPA;
                } else if (Capabilities.contains("WEP")) {
                    return WEP;
                } else {
                    return OPEN;
                }

            }
        }
        return null;
    }




}
```

> Call the method

```
ConnectionManager connectionManager=new ConnectionManager(context);
connectionManager.enableWifi();
connectionManager.requestWIFIConnection("YOUR_SSID","PASSWORD");
```

Comment: What is `Constants.SSID_NOT_FOUND` ??

Comment: i steel don't find changes with my code but for you worked! wired! by the way the way thanks a lot.