# What Permissions are needed in Android Connect to WiFi

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

What permissions does my app need to connect to a WiFi or change the current connected WiFi?
I've been trying the answers in the following StackOverflow link [How do I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect to a wifi network from within the app rather than relying on user interaction, you should need the following permissions:

```
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
```

Comment: I was missing the android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE thank you