# Implement a wifi barcode scanner

Tags: android, qr-code

In my app, i need to connect to a WiFi after scanning a QR code. How should i go about achieving this?

I tried reading the qr code and was successful in that using https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android . How should i use the data i get from the QR code to connect to a WiFi? The data i get is in the format: "Id:23,wifiName:wert,wifiPass:12345678"

I found out this library https://github.com/zxing/zxing but i am not able to formulate a method of how to use it?

I don't need the exact code. Just mention the correct method.

Comment: See if any of the answers here help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8818290/450534

Answer (score 2):

You have to tokenize the data which you received from qr code scan. you have data in form like `"Id:23,wifiName:wert,wifiPass:12345678"` so in order to tokinze this data , following method will give you the ssid and password in order to connect to the wifi.

```
 public String contentParsing(String content) {

    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(content, ":,;");
    String idLabel = tokens.nextToken();
    String idLabelValue = tokens.nextToken();
    String ssidLabel = tokens.nextToken();
    String ssid = tokens.nextToken();
    String passwordLabel = tokens.nextToken();
    String password= tokens.nextToken();
  }
```

To connect wifi

```
public static WifiConfiguration createWifiCfg(String ssid, String password, int type) 
     {
    WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
    config.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
    config.allowedProtocols.clear();

    config.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";

    if(type == WIFICIPHER_NOPASS){
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

       }
    else if(type == WIFICIPHER_WEP){
        config.hiddenSSID = true;
        config.wepKeys[0]= "\""+password+"\"";
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        config.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
        }else if(type == WIFICIPHER_WPA){
        config.preSharedKey = "\""+password+"\"";
        config.hiddenSSID = true;
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    }

    return config;
}
```

When you receive the data after scanning , pass that data to a string variable and call the method  `contentParsing(data)`