# Android change wifi network not working

Tags: android, networking, connection, wifi, wifimanager

I am trying to connect to a specific wifi network, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8818490/168175). However, while sometimes it works, most of the times it doesn't. I do not really understand why if I run the app, let's say 10 times, the device connects to my network 2 times, and the other 8 it doesn't.

In the following is the code I use in a Fragment.

```
WifiConfiguration wificonfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
wificonfiguration.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
wificonfiguration.priority = 40;
wificonfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;

// WPA management
wificonfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
wificonfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
wificonfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
wificonfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
wificonfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
wificonfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
wificonfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
wificonfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
wificonfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
wificonfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

int networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wificonfiguration);

if (networkId > -1) {
    boolean status = wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
}
```

The network configuration is actually added to the manager and `status` value is true. I have run it on several devices running Lollipop. Also, the network I want to connect to does not provide internet access, so I also thought that may be a problem for what stated in the note [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#enableNetwork(int,%20boolean)). Can anybody tell me if the code is ok?

**Solved**

The problem was solved by adding `wifiManager.disconnect();` before adding the new network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable all the network via below described method before adding the network. This would disable all the configured networks to auto-connect.

```
for (WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration_ : wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()) {

      wifiConfiguration_.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;
      int returnNetworkId_ = wifiManager.updateNetwork(wifiConfiguration_);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, but disconnecting through `wifiManager.disconnect();` did.