# How to connect to WIFI AP using static ip address, not DHCP

Tags: android-wifi

I'm looking for how to connect to WIFI AP and found this.

[How do I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)

And With the code above, I made up the below code.

```
public void connect_dhcp() 
{
    String sSSID = "TESTAP";
    String sPassword = "12341234";

    WifiConfiguration wfc = new WifiConfiguration();

    wfc.SSID = "\"".concat(sSSID).concat("\"");
    wfc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;
    wfc.priority = 40;

    wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
    wfc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
    wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);

    wfc.preSharedKey = "\"".concat(sPassword).concat("\"");

    WifiManager wfMgr = (WifiManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int networkId = wfMgr.addNetwork(wfc);
    if (networkId != -1) {

        Log.d("SCAN", "Success");
        wfMgr.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
    }

}
```

But I also need to connect with static ip.
Can anyone help me connect to WIFI AP with static ip?