# Reconnecting to a WiFi Network after disconnecting from it Programatically

Tags: java, android

I got disconnected from a WiFi network Programatically using

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 wifi.disconnect();
DisconnectWifi discon = new DisconnectWifi();
registerReceiver(discon, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));


public class DisconnectWifi extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
     WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(!intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_STATE).toString().equals(SupplicantState.SCANNING)) 
         wifi.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

But I am not able to reconnect to the same network again. I tried reconnecting by using:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.reconnect();
```

but was not able to connect. How can I now reconnect to WiFi Network?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

So the complete, simplified solution would look something like this:

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", key);

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
//remember id
int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

Hope it Helps You!!

Comment: In wifiConfig.preSharedKey I need to put my WiFi Password?

Comment: I Want to connect to same WiFi network from which i disconnected earlier to use mobile internet.

Comment: Put that wifi SSID and password it will connect ! try my above solution @Ramanujam

Comment: Hey I followed the same but it didn't connected

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically have a look on accepted answer and try this

Comment: My network type is WPA/WPA2 PSK I tried using above link but it didnt worked
String networkSSID = "G******st";
     String networkPass = "#G*********@*";

     WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
     conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
     
     conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
     
     WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
     wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

Comment: List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
     for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
         if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
              wifiManager.disconnect();
              wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
              wifiManager.reconnect();               

              break;
         }           
      }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109531/discussion-between-jhaman-das-and-ramanujam).

Comment: No bro my device is Moto G Android version : 6

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109531/discussion-between-jhaman-das-and-ramanujam