# How to login WiFi to WiFi particular mac address and password in android phone

Tags: android

How to login WiFi to WiFi particular mac address and password in android phone 
When we used android WiFi to connect any router can not connect password is right.

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();

        String networkSSID = "00:ac:1b:bc:00:37";
        String networkPass = "123456";

        Log.d(TAG, "# password " + networkPass);

        for (ScanResult result : results) {
            if (result.BSSID.equals(networkSSID)) {

                String securityMode = getScanResultSecurity(result);
                int res;
                if (securityMode.equalsIgnoreCase("OPEN")) {

                    wifiConfiguration.BSSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                    res = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
                    Log.d(TAG, "# add Network returned " + res);

                    boolean b = wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
                    Log.d(TAG, "# enableNetwork returned " + b);

                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

                } else if (securityMode.equalsIgnoreCase("WEP")) {

                    wifiConfiguration.BSSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
                    wifiConfiguration.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
                    wifiConfiguration.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                    res = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
                    Log.d(TAG, "### 1 ### add Network returned " + res);

                    boolean b = wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
                    Log.d(TAG, "# enableNetwork returned " + b);

                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    wifiConfiguration.BSSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
                    wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
                    wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = true;
                    wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
                    res = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
                    Log.d(TAG, "### 2 ### add Network returned " + res);

                    wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
                }

                boolean b = wifiManager.saveConfiguration();

                if (res != -1 && b) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "### Change happen");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "*** Change NOT happen");
                }
                btnClick.callOnClick();
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            }
        }
         private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            Log.e("MainActivity", "web view network check " + isNetworkAvailable());
            return true;
        }
    }
    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "button Click connected to " + isNetworkAvailable());
                mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
                setContentView(mWebView);
            }
        });
public String getScanResultSecurity(ScanResult scanResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "* getScanResultSecurity");

    final String cap = scanResult.capabilities;
    final String[] securityModes = {"WEP", "PSK", "EAP"};

    for (int i = securityModes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (cap.contains(securityModes[i])) {
            return securityModes[i];
        }
    }

    return "OPEN";
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: When we connect but not internet connect.