# How can I connect to a specific wifi network in iOS programatically?

Tags: c#, ios, c#-4.0, networking

I want to design an app which shows a list of wifi networks available and connect to the network when it is selected.

I want to do this for **iOS** (like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)  does  for Android).

Is this possible?
If so, please provide some basic information for implementation
(is. what classes should be used?)

Comment: You can't do this in an app on iOS.  This function is exposed to the user by the iOS settings app.

Comment: What about if the app knows the name of the network to expect, can I search for a named network within an app?