# How can i get the signal strong at real time?

Tags: android, multithreading, signals, wifi, async-onprogressupdate

Guys how can i use an Asynchronous task and run a loop that gets an updated RSSI on every iteration, and how can i update the UI with onProgressUpdate().

And for the last how can i use a Thread.sleep(500) in my loop to it updates every half second?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_wi_fi.htm) first. Basically you have to use the [WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) to scan for available networks and receive the result in a BroadcastReceiver as shown in the tutorial. You can extract any info available for the networks from the [ScanResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html).

After that everything is quite simple

Comment: Thanks for explication. I've done it. but now i need picked up the strongest signal of Wifi available.
I've to speak the wifi that is close, and when the signal weaken talk that is moving away. If you have a stronger signal will replace the previous signal... that's why i want to know how to use thread to update all moments.

Comment: What do you mean all the time? Get updates every time there is a change in the signal of a network or get updates every 1 or 5 minutes for example? You want this to run only when your app is in the foreground or also in the background? Give more details in your question.

Comment: i need to get the updates every 40 seconds , if the  current wifi signal is weaker than the another signal, then the strongest signal prevail. and I need this information at all times with the app is in the foreground and background.

Comment: Read this https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html and check the code sample for the alarm scheduler. And check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8818490/6774854 on how to connect to a wifi

Comment: I do not want to connect to Wifi. I only need to read the strongest signal and make the device speak  the network name, and when the signal ceases, talk that is moving away from the Wifi signal.

Comment: Good luck, then. You have everything you need.