# Can a mobile App (Android or IOS) be used for Wi-Fi Authentication (instead of Splash pages) for seamless guest experience

Tags: android, ios, authentication, wifi, wifimanager

I am working on a retail app. I would like to use the mobile app for allowing guests access to FREE Wi-Fi in their stores.

The ideal outcomes is if a user already has their mobile app, the user is automatically logged into the wi-fi without any manual intervention.

If the user does not have their mobile app, the user sees a Splash page and is given the option to download the mobile app. once the mobile app download is selected, he is given access to the network

3 specific questions:

1. Is there a way in which an app can get access to all available WIFI SSID's seen by Iphone / Andriod? and can the App then join a chosen SSID? How is this done
2. Is there a way in which the app then fills out the splash page information to get access? How is this done
3. Is there a recommended best practices for enabling this- i know this more of an opinion, but looking for any examples I could learn from.

Thanks,

NB: I have tried splash pages / captive portals but don't want that additional step that causes friction in adoption

Comment: I think this post should help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wi-fi-network-in-android-programmatically

Comment: thanks @Just_someone- this solves a big part of my problem