# Android - Connecting to specified wifi and check SSID

Tags: java, android, wifi

I tried to check that mobile is connecting to required wifi are not? So, I use this code.

```
(wifiInfo.getSSID().equals("WiredSSID"))
```

but it doesn't work. When I try to make toast name, it still shows "WiredSSID". So, I don't know what point is wrong.

Moreover, how can I connect to Captive Portal Wifi Automatically. I use the code from [How do I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-do-i-connect-to-a-specific-wi-fi-network-in-android-programmatically)

make it to OPEN type (conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);) and put it in OnCreate function, but it cant work. I don't know that I should change network type or not? Please help me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code snippet to check for available wifi networks and get connected to a specified wifi network

```
         List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifi.getScanResults();
         wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];

         for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
            wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).SSID);                

            if(wifis[i].equals("WiredSSID")) {

                 WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                 wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", wifis[i]);
                 wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", "password");

                 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
                 //remember id
                 int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
                 wifiManager.disconnect();
                 wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
                 wifiManager.reconnect();
             }
         }
```

Comment: Amazing! I can connect wifi now. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String networkSSID = "WiredSSID";
(wifiInfo.getSSID().equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\""))
```

Please note the quotes. String should contain ssid in quotes.

Comment: It works! Thank you. And could you explain me more in the second question about connect Captive Portal Wifi?

Comment: @SafeNo, I don't know what is Captive Portal Wifi, however, you might try to accept my answer and put the other question in another NEW question. Thank you.