# is it possible to connect to WPA-PSK secured network programmatically in android 6.0 marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-wifi

I am trying to connect on WPA-PSK secured  network on android devices.  The network is already configured to the device manually just disconnected. I got this kind of solution working on older devices. 
[How do I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-do-i-connect-to-a-specific-wi-fi-network-in-android-programmatically)

But it won't work on android 6.0

I found that  wificonficurations can not be  anymore modified in android 6.0 so does this mean it is not  even possible to do this on the android 6.0.  or  would  this  kind of approach  make it work. http://www.intentfilter.com/2016/08/programatically-connecting-to-wifi.html
I am just trying to figure is it  even possible to connect programmatically in wifi on android 6.0 and above. If it requires runtime  permission it's fine for my solution.

thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

I managed  to get it working problem was this  bug in 6.0.1  so that  enable network just gets stuck  reason was that 
`wifiManager.enableNetwork();`
gets stuck  if`wifiManager.addNetwork();` returns -1 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37069571
workaround  was to add network manually and  then get the network id
from `wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();` 
and call `enableNetwork();` with proper id.

still unclear  why adding network configuration always returns -1

Comment: reason was that adding fails if  the network has been added  before by another app or user. So  that's what  the change for 6.0 means about configuration  not allowed to be modified.