# Connect to drone wifi via an application

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I need an information about a connection to a drone WiFi. Is it possible to connect to a drone WiFi via an Android application? For example, there is a `button` "Connect" and when the user clicks the `button`, the phone automatically connects to the drone WiFi (the user does not need to go to phone settings and WiFi settings to connect to the WiFi drone, just clicks the "Connect" `button` on the application).

Comment: I sort Answer, YES. You can like what ever you want to do. If you don't have  SSID then you can search for it also.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

If you know drone's Wi-Fi network SSID and password then just connect to it like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8818490) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20504821). Don't forget to set `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` permission in manifest.