# Connecting to a specific Wi-Fi network programmatically

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-do-i-connect-to-a-specific-wi-fi-network-in-android-programmatically) where the answer present!

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
     wifiManager.disconnect();
     wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
     wifiManager.reconnect();               

     break;
}           
}
```

He is doing disconnect() before enabling particular SSID every time. 
I followed the same and it is working fine for me.

**But the question is why every time disconnect() needed before enable ?**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `wifiManager.disconnect()`. If needed connect to API 19-25. If you need the highest level 8-8.1 you must use it. You can try this [library](https://github.com/zoltanersek/android-wifi-activity).

But it has one bug - phone keeps the connection for just 35 seconds and after this, it returns to default wifi access point.

Comment: Ok.
Can you please tell why we must use wifiManager.disconnect() for 8-8.1? @Tvester