# how to get BSSID of all connected network?

Tags: android, android-wifi, bssid

i have used the below code but it was working well but after some month i am getting a result as **any** instead of getting **BSSID** value. here is my code. please guide me any other alternative way.

```
 @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
public void loadWifiAvailableList() {
    WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();

    String macAddr = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
    String bssid = wifiInfo.getBSSID();
   //here i am getting the proper bssid
    Log.d("bssid from get connection info",bssid);

    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiMan.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
        if(i.BSSID!=null)
     //here i am getting any from i.BSSID
        Log.d("bssid from get configured network",i.BSSID);

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "any"? Is that the String that's returned?

Comment: @ChrisNeve yes.

Comment: Can't you just use the WifiInfo.getBSSID() method? Is that not sufficient? Since it seems to work

Comment: WifiInfo holds information
on the network to which the device is currently connected, or the network to which it is connecting. but i need it for all, so i am using this getConfiguredNetworks() @ChrisNeve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out some solution why am i getting **any or null** string in **getConfiguredNetworks()** api in android. the reason behind is if we have the same SSID and same password at some scenario it is sending as **any or null** string. so **getConfiguredNetworks()** is not a right method when you are trying to connect with same ssid. so use **getScanResults()** Api instead of **getConfiguredNetworks()**. After some own research i have found it out. This problem will occur only when you get an **AP** list with **same ssid and password**.use the scan result and **add** that network in wifi configuration then connect it but this method was deprecated in **API level 26**. so it wont work from api **level 26**. [reference link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#saveConfiguration())

```
  //https://stackoverflow.com/a/8818490
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        //checking the right network.
        List<ScanResult> scanresults = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        {
            for (ScanResult scanresult : scanresults) {
                Log.d("scan result1", scanresult.BSSID + "");
 }}


 WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
    conf.BSSID = Bssid;
  WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  ///this wont work from api level 26
    wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
        if (i.BSSID != null && i.BSSID.equals(Bssid)) {
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            wifiManager.reassociate();
            Log.d("changing network", "connecting the right network");
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This one is deprecated as well in API level 26
I don't seem to find or understand the alternative

Answer (score 4):

I have also got the same problem. I solved it by the help of broadcast receiver and build my own logic around it.

Broadcast Receiver class, make sure for provided permissions **ACCESS_WIFI_STATE** and **CHANGE_WIFI_STATE** in manifest.

```
public class WifiChecker extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private OnWifiResultArrived onWifiResultArrived = null;
    private static boolean CAN_CALL_AGAIN = true;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;

    /**
     * @param context context of activity.
     * Remember to provide permission
     * <p>
     * {@code <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />},
     * {@code <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />}</p>
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public WifiChecker(Context context) {
        CAN_CALL_AGAIN = true;
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        context.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        wifiManager.startScan();

        rerunAgain();
    }

    private void rerunAgain() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (CAN_CALL_AGAIN)
                    wifiManager.startScan();

                rerunAgain();       //rerun the broadcast again
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    public void addListerForWifiCallback(OnWifiResultArrived onWifiResultArrived) {
        this.onWifiResultArrived = onWifiResultArrived;
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateUi(wifiManager.getScanResults());
    }

    private void updateUi(final List<ScanResult> scanResults) {

        try {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (onWifiResultArrived != null)

                            onWifiResultArrived.isInWifiRange(scanResults);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void unregisterListner(Context context) {
        this.onWifiResultArrived = null;
        CAN_CALL_AGAIN = false;
    }

    public interface OnWifiResultArrived {
        void isInWifiRange(List<ScanResult> scanResults);
    }
}
```

User of Broadcast class
Either **implement** the broadcast receiver class interface i.e.,**OnWifiResultArrived**

```
WifiChecker checker = new WifiChecker(this);
checker.addListerForWifiCallback(this);

@Override
public void isInWifiRange(List<ScanResult> scanResults){
    //get your BSSID here
    scanResults.get(position).BSSID;
    //write your logic for checking weather it is connected or not
}
```

or

```
WifiChecker checker = new WifiChecker(this);
checker.addListerForWifiCallback(@Override
public void isInWifiRange(List<ScanResult> scanResults){
    //get your BSSID here
    scanResults.get(position).BSSID;
   //write your logic for checking weather it is connected or not
});
```

Comment: thanks for your effort but this is ScanResult api, from this api i can get BSSID but i want to get the BSSID from getConfiguredNetworks();

Answer (score 2):

To get BSSID for currently connected WIFI network, use WiFiInfo class.

```
WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(
                        Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();

        String macAddr = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
        String bssid = wifiInfo.getBSSID();
```