# Possible to connect or to create a hotspot from Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a way to connect to a WiFi/hotspot for my multiplayer game on iOS and Android. Instead of going to settings and then connecting manually, is it possible to connect via script in Unity?

Comment: I don't think it is possible .. this would require that Unity/your app has permissions to directly change system settings. I don't know any app that directly is allowed to change WiFi settings (and probably wouldn't trust it very much). Usually they all redirect the user to the phones settings instead

Comment: @derHugo I had found something similar which was for android [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-do-i-connect-to-a-specific-wi-fi-network-in-android-programmatically

Comment: Check [prime31's plugins](https://prime31.com/).