# How to compatible with Android10.0 Wi Fi connection "addnetwork" method Return -1?

Tags: android, wifi

"Addnetwork" is used below Android 9.0. This method returns correctly, but it fails when Android 10.0 is used. It always returns - 1. What is the reason?
This is my core code:

```
    public WifiConfiguration createWifiInfo(String SSID, String Password,
                                        int Type) {
    WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
    config.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
    config.allowedProtocols.clear();
    config.SSID = "\"" + SSID + "\"";
    WifiConfiguration tempConfig = this.isExsits(SSID);
    if (tempConfig != null) {
        mWifiManager.removeNetwork(tempConfig.networkId);
    }

    if (Type == 1) // WIFICIPHER_NOPASS
    {
        config.wepKeys[0] = "";
        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        config.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    }
  
    return config;
}
```

Partial code:

```
 WifiConfiguration wifiInfo = createWifiInfo("", "", 1);
 networkId = mWifiManager.addNetwork(wifiInfo);//result: networkId:-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WifiManager.addNetwork(WifiConfiguration config)` has been [deprecated in API level 29](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration)).
Instead, developers are expected to use the `WifiNetworkSpecifier` or "Wi-Fi suggestion API" as stated in the link above. Both APIs show a different system dialog which asks the user to connect to a specified network.

You can find an example for the `WifiSuggestions` API in this StackOverflow thread: [Creating a custom wifi setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753528/creating-a-custom-wifi-setup/59755390#59755390)