# Xamarin Android connect to existing Wi-Fi AP

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-wifi

I spent an hour googling and everything I see boils down to a simple code:

```
var wifiManager = ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService).JavaCast<WifiManager>();

WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration() { Ssid = @"""ssid""", PreSharedKey = @"""passw""" };

var id = wifiManager.AddNetwork(conf);
var enabled = wifiManager.EnableNetwork(id, true);
```

if i set ssid/password to a WiFi which is in the list on my Android phone the id is -1 and nothing happens.

if i set those to a fictitious values like abc/abc I get a realistic id.

so I am not sure - what is the purpose of this code in real-life if you cannot connect to an existing Wi-Fi ?

**how do i connect to an 'existing' Wi-Fi in API level 29+?** 
*(by existing - I mean the phone has it stored in the list and it is currently visible in Wi-Fi scan)*

**What I really want is to switch to another Wi-Fi in my home when I move from one room to another**

`Xamarin.Forms 4.5 | Android 10.0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network in Android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-do-i-connect-to-a-specific-wi-fi-network-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: no it does exactly same thing `AddNetwork`

Comment: @BoppityBop Anything update? Now you solved your problem?

Comment: i didnt. gave up for now..

Answer (score 0):

**Please note that `WifiManager` API is deprecated and will cease to work when targeting Android Q SDK**

The [documentation of `addNetwork`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration)) says

> Add a **new network** description to the set of configured networks. [emphasis mine]

You - however - wrote

> if i set ssid/password to a WiFi which is in the list on my Android phone [...]

which is per definition not a **new network**, but an existing one, hence `addNetwork` fails and returns `-1`.

Try to use [`GetConfiguredNetworks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getConfiguredNetworks()) and filter the `List<WifiConfiguration>` by the field `WifiConfiguration.SSID`. You can then use `WifiConfiguration.NetworkId` for 
`EnableNetwork`.

Comment: can you answer the actual question - how do i do it ("properly") in API 29+?