# Detecting open WiFi networks

Tags: android, wifi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android: Determine security type of wifi networks in range (without connecting to them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866153/android-determine-security-type-of-wifi-networks-in-range-without-connecting-t)

Could someone help me see how to check for an open network in the list of available networks.

I am getting the list of networks.

```
List<ScanResult> results = wifiDemo.wifi.getScanResults();

ScanResult bestSignal = null;

for (ScanResult result : results) {
  if (bestSignal == null
      || WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(bestSignal.level, result.level) < 0)
    bestSignal = result;
}
```

How can I check for the open auth?

Comment: You need to look at the [`capabilities`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#capabilities) member of the `ScanResult`s

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`scanResult.capabilities`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#capabilities).