# Android - detecting if wifi is WEP, WPA, WPA2, etc. programmatically

Tags: android, wifi

I am looking for a programmatic way on Android to determine whether the WIFI my device is currently connected to is "secured" using either WEP, WPA, or WPA2.  I've tried Google searching and I cannot find a programmatic way to determine this.  I've also looked at the TelephonyManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) which also lacks this information.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Have you tried looking through [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) or [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)?

Comment: For the current network you can find what you need in the WifiConfiguration of the WifiManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html

Comment: have you got  solution for this ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a way using the ScanResult object.

Something like this:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<ScanResult> networkList = wifi.getScanResults();

//get current connected SSID for comparison to ScanResult
WifiInfo wi = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
String currentSSID = wi.getSSID();

if (networkList != null) {
    for (ScanResult network : networkList) {
        //check if current connected SSID
        if (currentSSID.equals(network.SSID)) {
            //get capabilities of current connection
            String capabilities =  network.capabilities;
            Log.d(TAG, network.SSID + " capabilities : " + capabilities);

            if (capabilities.contains("WPA2")) {
                //do something
            } else if (capabilities.contains("WPA")) {
                //do something
            } else if (capabilities.contains("WEP")) {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

References:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#capabilities

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html

[android: Determine security type of wifi networks in range (without connecting to them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866153/android-determine-security-type-of-wifi-networks-in-range-without-connecting-t/19567423#19567423)

[ScanResult capabilities interpretation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956874/scanresult-capabilities-interpretation)

Comment: You wouldn't need to check for both WPA and WPA2. Checking for WPA alone is sufficient.

Comment: @daniel . This shows capabilities supported by the access point. How to know that  which security is used for the current connection