# How to get encryption type of the current wifi connection without scanning all wifi networks?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, android-permissions, android-networking

Is there a way to get wifi encryption type (like WSA, WSA2, WEP) programmatically on Android 6.0+ without using:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<ScanResult> networkList = wifi.getScanResults();
```

because I don't want to have to ask user for access to location.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

which appears to be a requirement when scanning wifi networks.

I am hoping there is a way to get this without having to scan all wifi networks like in the android.net.wifi.WifiInfo class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO, this is not possible. The only way you have to get the encryption type of current running wifi is by using the `android.net.wifi.WifiInfo` or `ScanResults` using `iterations`.

You can use the below example to get encryption type of current running Wifi with `ScanResult`

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<ScanResult> networkList = wifi.getScanResults();

//get current connected SSID for comparison to ScanResult
WifiInfo wi = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
String currentSSID = wi.getSSID();

    if (networkList != null) {
        for (ScanResult network : networkList)
        {
           //check if current connected SSID
           if (currentSSID.equals(network.SSID)){
            //get capabilities of current connection
            String Capabilities =  network.capabilities;        
            Log.d (TAG, network.SSID + " capabilities : " + Capabilities);

            if (Capabilities.contains("WPA2")) {
               //do something
            }
            else if (Capabilities.contains("WPA")) {
               //do something
            }
            else if (Capabilities.contains("WEP")) {
               //do something
            }
           }
        }
    }
```

You can get the refferences from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28906046/4360419

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe it will be added to a future version of AOSP.

Comment: If you like my answer so, please mark it as helpful...!

Comment: Not going to accept the answer quite yet, maybe someone knows of an undocumented way to do this.