# Get the current wifi security used on Android

Tags: android, security, android-wifi, wpa, wep

I'm developping an app which may send sensitive data and I want to be sure that i don't send them on a public or weak protected network.
That's why I'd like to get the current security used on wifi network on Android.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19567423/3884856) but I'm not sure of the accuracy of the solution.
Indeed, the [allowedKeyManagement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html#allowedKeyManagement) method seems to return the supported protocols, but it's not explicitely said to return the **current** active protocol beeing used.
Is there a **sure way** to get the effective protection used on the cirrent wifi network ?

Thanks

Comment: WPA is not enough if the hacker/interested party is inside the network - http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12596/can-a-hacker-sniff-others-network-data-over-a-wireless-connection

Comment: Thank you for your answer; the fact is that i just want to be sure that the device is using a protected network (preferably WPA2) to increase mitigation of risks. If a method could just return safely and securely the exact protection used currently it would be really useful to perform what i'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest one method

1. Get list of all configured network using [getConfiguredNetworks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks()) API
2. Loop through all entries and find the current Network using [WifiConfiguration.status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html#status) API. The status should be [CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.Status.html#CURRENT) for current network
3. For that current network, get the [allowedKeyManagement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html#allowedKeyManagement) and check that it is not [NONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.html#NONE).

Comment: Thanks for your answer; but the documentation says "The set of key management 'protocolS' supported by this configuration". I read quite much posts relating to Android developpement and many developpers complain about mistakes in the doc; so would it be possible that this is actually a typo and the method returns only the current used ciphering, instead of the supported ones ?

Comment: In that case, it still solves your problem right? you can check if current cipher matches your needs and take action accordingly

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, e.g. : if the configuration allows WPA and WEP, how can I be sure that the network currently used between the device and the the access point is protected thanks to WPA and not WEP ?

Comment: I think you might have this issue with [virtual SSIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT#Version_history) ?