# Android: How to know if a Wifi is encrypted or not?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi

I have encountered a couple of methods that gives which encrpytion methods  supported by router. Is there any way to learn if a listed Wifi is encrypted or not?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866153/android-determine-security-type-of-wifi-networks-in-range-without-connecting-t