# Broadcast Receiver on an Open WiFi network found

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, wifi, android-wifi

I want to invoke a `BroadcastReceiver` on an open `WiFi` network found, So What should be the `Action` name in `IntentFilter` ?

```
<receiver android:name=".MyWiFiReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="?????????????" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
I used to check connectivity change.

```
<receiver android:name=".service.NetworkChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />

            <category android:name="com.example.quangtv" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I've college today, i'll check it later, Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such action that will filter the type of network.
That said, you can scan the networks upon change and check if their open using method as such:

```
static int getSecurity(ScanResult result) {

if (result.capabilities.contains("WEP")) {
    return SECURITY_WEP;
} else if (result.capabilities.contains("PSK")) {
    return SECURITY_PSK;
} else if (result.capabilities.contains("EAP")) {
    return SECURITY_EAP;
}
   return SECURITY_NONE;
}
```

I think this answer might help you (the method above is taken from there):
[android: Determine security type of wifi networks in range (without connecting to them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866153/android-determine-security-type-of-wifi-networks-in-range-without-connecting-t)

Comment: But udi, I'm getting a simple notification from the builtin WiFi app when ever a open wifi is found by the device. so i think there's some specific action correspond to the event. Anyways thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Well, you can achieve that by checking the networks this way after you've been notified by android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE