# Getting whether the wifi connection is locked(password protected) or not

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

In my app I am getting all available WiFi networks and displaying them in a list using `WifiManager.startScan()` and `WifiManager.getScanResults()`.Also I am able to show signal strength.But I don't know how to show whether wifi is locked or not.In the Settings screen it shows lock icon for wifi which are locked.How can i know whether wifi is password protected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`ScanResult.capabilities`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#capabilities)

An example is: `[WPA-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPA2-PSK-TKIP-CCMP][WPS][ESS]`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7019338/1395437) if you want to find a way of parsing it.

Basically, if you want to get if it is protected or not:

```
boolean isProtected = AccessPointState.getScanResultSecurity(scanResult) != AccessPointState.OPEN;
```

(although it is not nice to compare Strings with the == operator, this will always return the correct answer because the reference in AccessPointState is a `static final` one)

Comment: so I have to copy AccessPointState from ggogle project and add in my project?

Comment: You don't have to. Probably it is enough to copy that one method and the constants.

Comment: so if scanresults capabilites contains "PSK","WEP" or "EAP" that means wifi is password protected?