# Get last one week user connected WIFI data android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

In one of my android app, I am trying to display last one week user connected WiFi list with name, time of last connection and security level of WiFi like below

```
Router_WiFi   Open   At 08:30 PM Jan 02,2017

Sunny_WiFi   WPA2   At 08:40 PM Jan 05,2017

Another_WiFi   WEP   At 08:50 PM Jan 07,2017
```

I am able to get list of all configured WIFI networks by below snippet

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<WifiConfiguration> configuredNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
```

And their security type by using

[android: Determine security type of wifi networks in range (without connecting to them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866153/android-determine-security-type-of-wifi-networks-in-range-without-connecting-t)

But I'm don't know how to know weather a user connected to each WIFI, and last connected time

Thought I have lastConnected parameter in WifiConfiguration Object, It's always returning null. I am trying to get lastConnected parameter from configObject.toString() as I was unable to access as a public member of that class.

Can someone help me regarding this?

Comment: it return value only when last connection was successfully connected otherwise it return null. for eg if password was wrong then it failed to connect so no data will be available.

Comment: @Nas I connected to some WiFi successfully, but still unable to find lastConnected parameter in wifiConfiguration.toString() result

Comment: Could you pls post how you are getting lastConnected from WifiConfiguration object.

Comment: As for android documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html

Comment: @Nas Any update on this?